# use J to join comments

Tags: comments, join

Imagine I have comments

```
// line one
// line two
```

and I am on line one and want to join it with line two I will press `J` but that results in this:

```
// line one // line two
```

Instead of what I want

```
// line one line two
```

can I change the behaviour of `J` so that it works like this for comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set fo+=j
```

`:h fo-table`:

```
...
j   Where it makes sense, remove a comment leader when joining lines.  For
    example, joining:
        int i;   // the index ~
                 // in the list ~
    Becomes:
        int i;   // the index in the list ~
...
```

- default `formatoptions` in vim8 : `tcq`
- default `formatoptions` in neovim : `tcqj`