# Joining lines on Vim removes random characters

Tags: join

I have just noticed on my version of Vim (vim-tiny package on FreeBSD)

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jul  5 2021 16:53:06)
Included patches: 1-3081
Compiled by root@130amd64-quarterly-job-09
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

If I attempt to join lines, the line beginning in a * will have its * removed. For example:

```
/*****************************
 *
 * Line 1
 * Line 2
 * Line 3
 *
 *****************************/
```

If I go to Line 2 and press 'J', I end up with:

```
/*****************************
 *
 * Line 1
 * Line 2 Line 3
 *
 *****************************/
```

I would expect more sane behavior to be:

```
/*****************************
 *
 * Line 1
 * Line 2 * Line 3
 *
 *****************************/
```

Is there any way I can disable this unexpected "smart" behaviour? I am not sure what version of Vim it was introduced.

Comment: `:setl fo-=j`, please read the help at `:h fo-j`

Comment: Ah great, setting fo to the Vi default, rather than Vim is exactly what I needed. Many thanks! Now knowing the option I was looking for, there is some additional info here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/use-j-to-join-comments

Comment: Here's someone asking for the opposite...could be considered a dupe: [use J to join comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19962)

Comment: It does yes. I did do a search before I posted mine and because I wasn't specifically searching using the keyword "comments", I never spotted this one.

Comment: No worries. You didn't know what to search for. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure, but it looks like the question linked here in the comments is an acceptable dupe based on the conversation, so I'm going to move forward with closure. There are paths to re-open if that is not the case (editing, flagging, etc.)